# Conditional probability of intersections.

Tags: probability

I was reading through a paper and I came across the following equality: 
$$ 
P(X|Y, \pi) = \frac{P(X,Y|\pi)}{P(Y|\pi)} = \frac{P(X,Y|\pi)}{p(X_{1},Y|\pi) + P(X_{2}, Y|\pi)}
$$ 
where $Y$ is a fixed event and $\pi$ a fixed amount.

I was unsure as to how the author has rearranged the rhs, I am familiar with the conditional probability rules:
$$ 
P(a|b) = \frac{P(a \cap b)}{P(b)}
$$
and 
$$
P(a|b) = \frac{P(b|a)P(a)}{P(b)}
$$ 
but I can't seem to implement them to rearrange in the way which the author has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\P{\mathop{\mathsf P}}$

It is basically

$$\begin{align}
       \tag {1} \P(A\mid B\cap C) ~&=~\dfrac{\P(A\cap B\cap C)}{\P(B\cap C)}
\\[2ex]\tag {2} & =~ \dfrac{\P(A\cap B\mid C)\P(C)}{\P(B\mid C)\P(C)}
\\[2ex]\tag {3} & =~ \dfrac{\P(A\cap B\mid C)}{\P(B\mid C)}
\\[2ex]\tag {4} & =~ \dfrac{\P(A\cap B\mid C)}{\P(A\cap B\mid C)+\P(A^\complement\cap B\mid C)}
\end{align}$$